# Direct download image from link

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, href

i am wondering if there is a way to make a direct download link for image ?
When i do something like this:

It opens the image in the browser or in new tab. I want when user click on that link to download the image instantly. Is there a way to do this with HTML/CSS or with ASP.NET MVC 3 ?

My page is something like tumblr blog with several images on the main page and "Download HQ" button next to each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add HTTP Header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.ext>
```

Where  is the filename you want to appear in SaveAs dialog (like finances.xls or mortgage.pdf) - without < and > symbols.

Heres an example of this in MVC framework:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    var document = ...
    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        // for example foo.bak
        FileName = document.FileName, 

        // always prompt the user for downloading, set to true if you want 
        // the browser to try to show the file inline
        Inline = false, 
    };
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    return File(document.Data, document.ContentType);
}
```

Comment: What should i put instead the 3 dots from "var document = ..." ?

Comment: You dont need the "document" variable if you have no such container class in your project. Instead, you can just replace the places where its used, with your actual data variables.

Answer (score 2):

You will need server side scripting to make the link downloadable, you need to set the header to

```
Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=some.jpg
```

And then read the content of the image and flush it to response object.

here is an example for asp.net

***[Example](http://forums.asp.net/post/2109808.aspx)***

Comment: Ok i got an idea from the example, ty